# Azure app service with multiple production slots

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Let's say I have an azure app service with 4 slots used for production, each one with a 25% traffic.

Is it possible to have just one pre slot and swap it to the four production slots? Or how would you achieve this? We've thought of having 4 pre slots, one for every production slot, but seems a bit of a mess, surely there's a better option to have multiple production slots and the benefits of swapping...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using 4 slots, all for production?

Comment: You will not find a solution to this problem, please refer to my answer, it should be helpful for you to understand the slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The concept of slot.**

[Set up staging environments in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots)

---

Simply put, when creating a webapp, the default webapp belongs to the Production slot. At this time, we can create other slots.

Under normal circumstances, a test slot is usually created, and the test slot is updated with the latest program, so that the latest program can be deployed during swap. Generally, when the program has new functions, it is used for some users to distribute traffic. When there are different versions of the program that need to be run at the same time, then you can create the same 4 slots as you.

But your 4 slots, you want to achieve the purpose of updating all 4 slots through a swap operation. This is really strange. This is why [CSharpRocks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793891/csharprocks) asks you in conmment. Because your 4 slots are in the same app services plan, creating 4 slots will not improve performance.

---

## You may be thinking of multiple instances to extend your webapp, which can improve the performance of your webapp.

[image]

Comment: Yes, exactly, I misunderstood. What I really want is to scale out to multiple instances of my app. I see the multislot thingy is useful for a/b testing, anyway